# Scala function that accepts array argument and returns a mutated array

Tags: arrays, scala, list, string-interpolation

I would like to figure out the most pragmatic way to accept an array (or list) and append to the data structure. Then finally return the new data structure.

Something like this:

```
 def template(array: Array[String]): Array[Nothing] = {
  val staging_path = "s3//clone-staging/"
  var path_list = Array()
  //iterate through each of the items in the array and append to the new string.
  for(outputString <- array){
    var new_path = staging_path.toString + outputString
    println(new_path)
    //path_list I thought would add these new staging_path to the array
    path_list +: new_path

  }
 path_list(4)
 }
```

However, calling a single index of the data structure as a shanty way of checking existence, path_list(4) returns an Out of Bounds.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `path_list(4)` is doing there, but a much more idiomatic solution would be something like `def template(values: List[String]) = values.map("s3//clone-staging" + _)`.

Comment: Just trying to return a single index from the new data structure as a way to check if it exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to use `map` here:

```
val staging_path = "s3//clone-staging/"
val dirs = Array("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
val paths = dirs.map(dir => staging_path + dir)
println(paths)
// result: paths: Array[String] = Array(s3//clone-staging/one, s3//clone-staging/two, s3//clone-staging/three, s3//clone-staging/four, s3//clone-staging/five)
println(paths.length)
// result: 5
```

In functional programming land you are generally trying to avoid mutations. Instead, think of it as transforming your input array into a new array.

Comment: Avoiding the original mutation of the data structure is what I was attempting by creating the local  var path_list = Array()

Comment: @tjmorri7 if this solved your problem, please consider accepting this answer. If it does not, for whatever reason, please leave a comment explaining why it does not, so the answer could be improved. - Take a look to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).